# using "confusion" as a countable noun

Tags: word-usage

Can I use the word confusion in a countable sense?

For example, can I say like this:

> She was very considerate and observing and noticed **every little
>   confusion** that I would have every now and then.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is completely natural; except that the repetition of "every" is a little awkward. I would drop the second "every".

Many abstract nouns that are normally uncountable can be used countably for "instances of (whatever)".